# Getting access to the value range of planning collection inside the constraint stream

Tags: optaplanner

New to Optaplanner. Have looked at it before but the introduction of the Stream API made so much more accessible. I am working on an Employee scheduling solution (like so many others I guess) and fairness in shift distribution is always a hot topic. I read up on the topic and got inspired by this solution to the problem:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124232/formula-for-a-fairness-variance/2144813#2144813

But to do this you need access to the entire value range of Employees in your constraint stream, not only the ones that are assigned. I suppose there can be different expected number of assigned shifts based on your work conditions, not just the sum divided by the number of employees.

The models look like this

```
@PlanningSolution
public class ShiftRooster {
  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
  private List<ShiftAssignment> shiftAssignments;
    
  @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
  private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
}

@PlanningEntity
public ShiftAssignment {
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"employeeRange"})
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Then in your ConstraintProvider you do can do various way to collect the summary :

```
private Constraint unfairnessDayShift1(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
        .filter(shiftAssignment -> shiftAssignment.isDayShift())
        .groupBy(ShiftAssignment::getEmployee, ConstraintCollectors.count())
        .penalizeConfigurable("Unfairness1", (employee, count) -> count);
}

private Constraint unfairnessDayShift2(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
       .filter(shiftAssignment -> shiftAssignment.isDayShift())
       .groupBy(ConstraintCollectors.toMap(ShiftAssignment::getEmployee, 
                                           ShiftAssignment::getShift))
      .penalizeConfigurable("Unfairness2", (shiftMap) -> getUnFairness(shiftMap));
}
```

If you take nr2 you would like compare the map with the complete list of employees to return a single unfairness value for the entire schedule but how do get I access to the list of all Employees (ie the value range of Employee) at this point?

Do I need to assign the valueprovider on the ShiftAssignment instead? Does Optaplanner manage that the valuerange list is not duplicated for every ShiftAssignment it is attached to?

Or do I just Join on Employee before I collect the stream? But that feels like blowing up the stream in size.

SideNote:
In "unfairnessDayShift2" I would like to collect the list of shifts to a simple count but I can not find the API for it (or how I do it).

Java Stream:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(ShiftAssignment::getEmployee, 
      Collectors.filtering(s -> s.isDayShift(),Collectors.counting())));
```

**Update**

I looked at the Tennis example with the custom loadbalancer to calculate the unfairness but it aggregates over teams in TeamAssignments, where I have ShiftAssignment with both an Employee and a Shift. However, if I simply try to Collect the stream like this :

```
private Constraint test2(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
          .groupBy(ConstraintCollectors.toMap(ShiftAssignment::getEmployee, ShiftAssignment::getShift))
            .penalize("Test2",  HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (employeeShiftMap) -> 1);
}
```

This would supposedly aggregate over all assigned Employees and their respective Shifts into a `Map<Employee>, Set<Shift>>` but it does not work and I get this error from OptaPlanner :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undo for (ShiftAssignment...) does not exist`. Looking at the LoadBalance example I see that you implement the AccumulateFunction. Is that what I need to do to support this Accumulation?

Because if I do this:

```
private Constraint test1(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
            .groupBy(ShiftAssignment::getEmployee, ConstraintCollectors.toSet(ShiftAssignment::getShift))
            .penalize("Test1",  HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (employee, shiftSet) -> 1);
}
```

I get a stream of Employees and their Set of Shifts. Or can I collect this instead to get the desired `Map<Employee>, Set<Shift>>`?

I tried the AllEmployees class and it works but you must mean `@ProblemFactProperty` and not `@PlanningFact`?

Comment: In the tennis ConstraintProvider we deal with fairness/load-balancing: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/tennis/optional/score/TennisConstraintProvider.java#L37

Comment: If all the employees are facts (= never change), you could create a dummy `AllEmployees` class (containing all the employees somehow) and add it as a `@PlanningFact`. Then you can use `AllEmployees` in a `from()` or `join()` directly. That said, this is a bit hackish - joining on `Employee` could be OK, unless you suffer in performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. Will look into the examples and your suggestions.

Comment: @Lukáš Petrovický. I updated the original question from the latest trials.

Comment: You're correct on the `@ProblemFactProperty` instead of `@PlanningFact`. Turns out I don't remember our own annotations anymore. :-)

Comment: @LukášPetrovický :) Right not I am stuck at the ConstrainCollect problem where I can not see why my Collection breaks the Optaplanners internal optimization by throwing an Exception. I have not seen any examples that uses .groupBy as I tried to do. Even went through your Presentation from Optaplanner week but no further insight. Thank you very much again for all the help.

Comment: That issue is pretty hard to explain. Long story short: make sure your `equals()` and `hashCode()` work properly. Make sure your `hashCode()` never references anything that can change - for example, don't put planning variables in `hashCode()`. If it still fails then, we may have a bug on our hands, at which point I'll need some kind of a code reproducer.

Comment: I went through my `equals()` and `hashCode()` and ShiftAssignment included the `@PlanningVariable` in both identity methods so shame on me. However, now that I run `test2()` I get an NPE. My planning variable is not nullable and I even added a filter to make sure neither Employee or Shift is null before running the Collect.toMap.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors$ToMapPerKeyCounter.lambda$remove$1(ConstraintCollectors.java:1172)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap.compute(HashMap.java:1228)
 at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors$ToMapPerKeyCounter.remove(ConstraintCollectors.java:1171)` @LukášPetrovický if you think is a bug on your side I can provide my source if want.

Comment: In that case, source code and a data set would help. Feel free to get in touch with me on Zulip.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický,  Wrote to you on Zulip.